# Python USD to Satoshi

Tags: bitcoin

Looking for a method of converting $100, $130, $300 amounts into Satoshi to tell customers exactly how much to BTC to send.

Looked at Cryptocompare a little but was unable to find anything that dealt in amounts.

Comment: Do you need to current btc exchange rate?

Comment: @Suman correct!  Looking for the **current** amount at order time.  Thanks.

Comment: Please check the answer is working or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use blockchain.info api, they provide this service.

Link : https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=500

and you visit

Link : https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_api